Adding multiple worksheets to a single spreadsheet in R
How do I write multiple data frames (So for example df1 df2 and df3) to a single Excel Spreadsheet
but in separate named worksheets. So again for example:
Create the spreadsheet called "Example_Data.xlsx" with worksheets "Sheetdf1", "Sheetdf2" and "Sheetdf2"
I have tried the writexlsx() function and keep getting errors.
I have seen multiple instances online (at this website for example https://www.learnbyexample.org/read-and-write-excel-files-in-r/)
suggesting that the following code (using some example R dfs) will do that
# Write the first data set
write.xlsx(iris, file = "mydata.xlsx",
           sheetName = "IRIS", append = FALSE)

# Add a second data set
write.xlsx(mtcars, file = "mydata.xlsx",
           sheetName = "CARS", append = TRUE)

# Add a third data set
write.xlsx(Titanic, file = "mydata.xlsx",
           sheetName = "TITANIC", append = TRUE)

This code does not work (Note I am using my own file name and path when I run the code ...just not listing it here). Changing the append to = FALSE does not work either. The spreadsheet always has exactly the same thing, one worksheet and always the last one appended. overwrite = FALSE does not work. I get an error
Error in saveWorkbook(wb, file = file, overwrite = overwrite) :
File already exists!
overwrite=TRUE is default but I've changed that just to be sure. Back to square one. No errors but only the last sheet is written. What am I missing?

write.xlsx2 used to be a solution to this problem ...but that function doesn't seem to exist anymore...of COURSE...

With package writexl it's easy, just pass a named list of data frames. Note that Titanic is not a df. df_list <- list(IRIS = iris, MTCARS = mtcars) and then writexl::write_xlsx(df_list, "so_test.xlsx").

Please report what package you are using in your question. If you are using openxlsx, the examples show how to use a list to write multiple sheets.

Rui Barradas   the Titanic df was an example was used on the webpage I referenced perhaps it was something they used in another example ...no idea I have managed to find a solution that I prefer in openxlsx2 a new package which apparently replaced openxlsx. Thank you both for your comments.

The easiest way to save multiple data sets to an Excel file is to put the data into a list:
df_list <- list(iris= iris, mtcars= mtcars)

Two R packages that can save data stored in a list to Excel files are writexl and openxlsx.
library(writexl)
writexl::write_xlsx(df_list, file="writexl.xlsx")

library(openxlsx)
openxlsx::write.xlsx(df_list, file="openxlsx.xlsx")

The new and improved openxlsx2 package also has a similar function.
library(openxlsx2)
openxlsx2::write_xlsx(df_list, file="openxlsx2a.xlsx")

However, if your data are not in a list, openxlsx2 also has another way of saving data to Excel files using wb_add_data.
wb <- wb_workbook()
wb$add_worksheet("iris")
wb$add_data("iris", iris)

wb$add_worksheet("mtcars")
wb$add_data("mtcars", mtcars)

wb_save(wb, file = "openxlsx2b.xlsx")

Or, if there are many data frames to save:
data <- c("iris", "mtcars", "airquality", "PlantGrowth", "ToothGrowth")

wb <- wb_workbook()

invisible(lapply(data, \(x) {
  wb$add_worksheet(x)
  wb$add_data(x, get(x))
}))

wb_save(wb, file = "openxlsx2c.xlsx")


Edward, Thanks very much for the help.
